# Use mail authentication with appinventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

Can i use email authentication with appinventor. I just want to press a button and send a fixed email to a specific email address(gmail) using my email address(authenticate that is a valid gmail address)?

Answer (score 0):

**To send an email with App Inventor** after pressing a button, there are the following possibilities:

- [Scott's php example](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/app-inventor-developers-library/-6XI0hWHqao/1zzc0jEm0iwJ), which uses a php server and also offers the opportunity to send an attachment.
- [ShivalWolf's TinyWebDB example](http://ai.kittywolf.net/index.php/WolfWebEmail2). This solution also also offers the opportunity to send an attachment.
- [eiXerITS's modification of ShivalWolf's solution](http://eixerits.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/371/).
- and [my solution](http://puravidaapps.com/sendmail.php), which uses a Google Spreadsheet together with a Google Apps Script